# Nagios network traffic monitoring plugin for FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, nagios

Is there a Nagios network traffic plugin for FreeBSD machines? I have been using the following plugin on Ubuntu which uses /proc/net/dev and thus not supported in FreeBSD.
https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Network-Connections%2C-Stats-and-Bandwidth/check_eth/details